# Save PDF file in disk

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview

All hi!
I need to somehow save the PDF file on the iphone. I open the site in UIWebVIew and there is a link to download a PDF file, but PDF file open in UIWebView. Is there a way to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

In UIWebView delegate you can handle the navigation notification and prevent it; from the notification you will know the PDF URL, that will allow you to use NSURLConnection to download it.

Comment: Not quite clear. Let's start with a simple: there is a direct link to the PDF file. How this upload in the iphone and where to look this file then?

Comment: see the answer by sergio below

Comment: if you have a direct URL, you should: 1. create NSURL instance from the NSString with your URL; 2. create NSURLRequest instance from the NSURL instance; 3. create NSURLConnection instance with NSURLRequest instance; 4. handle NSURLConnection delegate for accumulating received NSData and save it in Caches or tmp directory of your sandbox.

Comment: or you can use handy ASIHTTPRequest library, see more details at http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [question/answer from S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076347/downloading-files-from-uiwebview-in-iphone-sdk/8077135#8077135) It includes sample code for both detecting that you are downloading a document and the actual saving to disk...

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

 if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqual:@"http"] && 
     [[[request URL] pathExtension]...])
        <your download/save code here>
        return NO;  //-- no need to follow the link
 }
 return YES; //-- otherwise, follow the link
```

}