# Downloading files from uiwebview in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

Is there any way to download file from `UIWebView` i am using this code on my `IBAction` event

```
- (IBAction)saveFile:(id)sender {
// Get the URL of the loaded ressource
NSURL *theRessourcesURL = [[self.webDisplay request] URL];
NSString *fileExtension = [theRessourcesURL pathExtension];

if ([fileExtension isEqualToString:@"png"] || [fileExtension isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || 
    [fileExtension isEqualToString:@"pdf"] || [fileExtension isEqualToString:@"html"]) {
    // Get the filename of the loaded ressource form the UIWebView's request URL
    NSString *filename = [theRessourcesURL lastPathComponent];
    NSLog(@"Filename: %@", filename);
    // Get the path to the App's Documents directory
    NSString *docPath = [self documentsDirectoryPath];
    // Combine the filename and the path to the documents dir into the full path
    NSString *pathToDownloadTo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docPath, filename];


    // Load the file from the remote server
    NSData *tmp = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:theRessourcesURL];
    // Save the loaded data if loaded successfully
    if (tmp != nil) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        // Write the contents of our tmp object into a file
        [tmp writeToFile:pathToDownloadTo options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to save the file: %@", [error description]);
        } else {
            // Display an UIAlertView that shows the users we saved the file :)
            UIAlertView *filenameAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"File saved" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The file %@ has been saved.", filename] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [filenameAlert show];
            [filenameAlert release];
        }
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" 
                                                        message:@"File could not be loaded" 
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        // File could notbe loaded -> handle errors
    }
} else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" 
                                                    message:@"File type not supported" 
                                                   delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    // File type not supported
}
```

}
this code open the file in `UIWebView` , which i want to download and when i press the button the opened file get save.
But i want my `UIWebView` to behave like normal browser , when the download link appear in it and user press it, `UIWebView` show dialog with option open it or save it if user press save the file get save automatically and if user press open it file should open in `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can provide `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest` in your `UIWebViewDelegate` so that each time the user is about to move to another web page, you have the chance to check what the link looks like:

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

     if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqual:@"http"] && 
         [[[request URL] pathExtension]...])
            <your download/save code here>
            return NO;  //-- no need to follow the link
     }
     return YES; //-- otherwise, follow the link
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Sergio for your answer and for your response your commented line guide me alot :)

Comment: @Sergio  If I try to download a file (may be from a yahoo/exchange server) it will have scheme as **bold** https **bold** and the pathExtension is some random string for eg. ashx etc...! How do I prompt the download of such files! Any idea on this ?